# Filtering data based on dynamic check box Categories in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angular-filters

I'm trying to achieve a filter check box option with dynamic data by category and sub category.

How I want is,

```
[] Category
  [] Sub Category
  [] Sub Category
[] Category
  [] Sub Category
  [] Sub Category
  [] Sub Category 

... and so on
```

Assume `[]` as check box above.

Here's the sample json data :

```
  [

   {

      "category": {

         "name": "AAA - 1"

      },

      "parentcategory": {

         "name": "AAA"

      },

      "title" : "XXXXX",

   },

   {

      "category": {

         "name": "AAA - 2"

      },

      "parentcategory": {

         "name": "AAA"

      },

      "title" : "YYYY",

   }

]
```

Based upon the above data, what i'm really trying to want is,

Sidebar :

```
[] AAA
  [] AAA - 1 
  [] AAA - 2
```

Main Content :

Initially show title. After something is checked, show title which are related to that category/sub category.

**Note** : Pl don't think that I'm asking without any effort. I've seen some examples like in [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/weyov/45/edit?html,js,output), but i couldn't find something like i wanted to achieve. Btw I'm new to Angular.

Comment: I don't think you organized your data very well. why not nesting children categories inside yout parent category?

Comment: how do the data to be? sample?

Comment: [ "parentCategory1": { "childCategory1": { "title": ..., ... }, childCategory2": { "title": ..., ... }}, "parentCategory2"...

Comment: how do i filter? Isn't that my question?

Comment: @SatejS There you go http://plnkr.co/edit/V28hhXN8T1hd7oLKQNuU?p=preview

Comment: I agree with @KobiCohen, your data could be structured much more parse-friendly.

Comment: Let's start with this @user3289108 [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/LZ5xeDVTc96rZGtEYFbx?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you want something like that:
http://jsfiddle.net/ms403Ly8/67/

Firstly i found first parent item from your json array. Then found this parent's children and add into it.

```
     angular.forEach($scope.itemList, function(itm) {
        var filteredItem = $filter('filter')($scope.itemList, { parentcategory: itm.parentcategory.name});
            if($filter('filter')($scope.parentItems, { name: itm.parentcategory.name}).length == 0){
                $scope.parentItems.push({name: itm.parentcategory.name, children:filteredItem});
            }
     });
```